# Matlab GUI: dialog box delayed closing

Tags: matlab, user-interface, dialog, delay

I'm writing a GUI in which I need a dialog box to show up under certain conditions. The problem is that closing the dialog box briefly freezes the GUI, for anything from a second to 5-6 seconds.

*Edit:* More precisely, once the dialog is opened, it needs a certain amount of time before it can be closed. If I wait a while before trying to close it, there is no delay. After closing the dialog, any other GUI operation on the figure itself (including closing) also requires me to wait a few seconds before it can be completed.

The smallest example I've come up with is the following:

```
function testdlg(varargin)

if nargin >= 1 && isnumeric(varargin{1})
    n = varargin{1};
else
    n = 9;
end

main = figure;
for i = 1:n
    for j = 1:n
        uicontrol('style', 'pushbutton', 'string', [int2str(i) ', ' int2str(j)], ...
            'units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.101*(i-1) + 0.0 0.06*(j-1) + 0.4 0.1 0.05], ...
            'callback', @displayDialog);
    end
end

if ~any(strcmpi(varargin, 'noax'))
    axes('units', 'normalized', 'position', [0 0.01 0.3 0.3]);
end

uiwait(main);

end

function displayDialog(varargin)

d = dialog('name', 'Dialog');
uiwait(d);

end
```

To describe this briefly: the function creates a grid (9x9 by default) of push buttons and a set of axes in a figure. A callback function is used so that clicking on any of the push buttons opens an empty dialog box.

What happens is the following. If the callback is never called (*i.e.*, no button is clicked) and the figure is closed, everything is fast and there is no delay. If, however, a button is clicked and the dialog shows up, trying to close the dialog soon after it was open exhibits a long delay (about one second on my machine) before it actually closes. When attempting to close the figure quickly after the dialog closed, there is a similarly long delay for the figure to close. Any other GUI interaction is also delayed (so pushing a button to open another dialog box exhibits a one second delay as well).

*Edit:* I updated the text above a little bit: the delays don't actually seem to happen when trying to perform the GUI operations, but rather after each GUI operation (like opening or closing the dialog, but only if the dialog is ever opened), there are a few seconds during which the GUI is inoperative.

Both the axes and the push buttons are important for this behavior. If you remove the axes (by calling `testdlg noax`), there is no delay. Reducing the number of buttons to a 5x5 grid or smaller (by calling, *e.g.,* `testdlg(5)`) also gets rid of the delay. Since there is no noticeable delay in these cases, the delay I'm seeing can't just be due to the sum of the times it takes Matlab to handle one axes and the time it takes to handle >25 buttons: the delay I see is much longer than the sum of the delays I see when only the axes or only the buttons are displayed. So the effect must somehow be due to an interaction between the axes and the buttons.

Here's what I know from the tests I've done:

- this is *not* due to the `uiwait` calls: removing them completely does not affect the delay
- this is *not* due to the dialog box being modal (adding `'WindowStyle', 'normal'` doesn't change anything)
- it's also *not* due to it being a dialog box (using a second `figure` instead of a `dialog` exhibits the same behavior)
- I've also tried setting all the axes options that are set to `'auto'` by default to `'manual'`, with no success
- this is also *not* due to giving callbacks to all the push buttons; removing the callbacks and using an extra button for opening the dialog exhibits the same delays
- changing `'pushbutton'` to `'popup'` doesn't change the delay, though there is some change in the appearance of the dropdown menus after the dialog box is closed, which slowly reverts back to normal over a second or so
- using `'text'` controls instead of `'pushbutton'` or `'popup'` does get rid of the delay.

Has anyone else noticed anything like this before? Is Matlab trying to do some layout calculations whose complexity grows quickly when axes are surrounded by many buttons? Is there a way to stop it from doing what it's trying to do?

The profiler shows a lot of time spent in Matlab's default `closereq` function that's called when the user attempts to close a window. All this does is essentially delete the figure. However, if I set my own `CloseRequestFcn` and try to time the `delete` call, it takes very little time.

I'm pretty stumped at this point -- if this is a bug, it's a very confusing one. Any ideas are very welcome. I'm running R2015b (8.6.0.267246) on Mac OS 10.11.6, if that's of any help.

Comment: ahve you tried using `profile` to check what takes so long? that a great way to check for stuff like this. try `profile viewer` and run your code in there. unfortunately (or fortunately) your example doenst come up with any latencies on my machine

Comment: For what it's worth, on Matlab 2013a, win10, the example code works perfectly fine and doesn't exhibit any delay ...

Comment: @Finn, yes, I wrote about that in my question: the profiler shows that the time is spent in the <code>closereq</code> function.

Comment: Finn, @Hoki: interesting that it doesn't show up for you. Upon further experimentation, it looks like the delay isn't necessarily at the end of the dialog: if I let the dialog box sit for a few seconds before closing it, it closes instantly. I then have to also let the figure sit for a while after having closed the dialog box for it to close properly. You see none of this? Could you also try/have you tried using a large grid, something like <code>testdlg(15)</code>? Thanks!

Comment: `testdlg(15)`, or event 20, does not have any more delay for me (note that it only display a 10x10 grid though, the extra `uicontrols` are out of the visible part. You may have to review your positioning code ...)

Comment: @Hoki thanks for trying. Could you please also try it with a `'popup'` instead of a `'pushbutton'` control? That makes the delay longer on my machine. Upon more experimentation, it seems like the problem is that, at least on my machine, dropdown menus (and presumably push buttons, too) change appearance when the figure loses focus. This takes a while to propagate when there are many of them, and for some reason it's a lot longer when some axes are also present. But the right thing to do would be to ask a separate question about this, right?